# How to add a program path in enviroment variable, with installer or in python?

Tags: python, environment-variables, imagemagick, ghostscript

I have a Python script that require the action of various programs (ImageMagick and Ghostscript) and need those programs to be in the system enviroment variables.

On my machine it is okay because I manually install the program and put it in the path. The problem is when i want to distribute the Python script, because I want the user to be able to install the program and put it automatically in their enviroment variables. Is there a way to do this with an installer, or in Python?

I have the executable of my python script to distribute, with PyInstaller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the script's current path to the system's PATH variable using:

```
import sys
from os.path import dirname

sys.path.append(dirname(__file__))
```

or

```
import sys
from os import getcwd

sys.path.append(getcwd())
```